# Finding JSON objects in mongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to find objects using the built it queries and It just doesn't work..
My JSON file is something like this:

```
{   "Text1":
    {
        "id":"2"
    },
    "Text2":
    {
       "id":"2,3"
    },
    "Text3":
    {
       "id":"1"
    }
}
```

And I write this `db.myCollection.find({"id":2})`
And it doesn't find anything.
When I write `db.myCollection.find()` it shows all the data as it should.

Anyone knows how to do it correctly?

Comment: There is no genreric query for your data-structure. Anyway use db.b.find({$or : [{"Text1.id":'2'}, {"Text2.id":'2'}, {"Text3.id":'2'}]})

Comment: gives me unexpected token :  . what do you mean There is no genreric query for your data-structure?
Isnt that how you write json. I saw it online in many times

Comment: What do you expect as your result?

Comment: I want for example to write db.myCollection.find({"id":1}) and return text3 and all its components (here there arent but in my object there is)

Comment: Could you change your data structure if its possible?

Comment: I can. how will it help me?

Comment: @Disposer I think he does not need to change his data structure. Please check my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its hard to change the data-structure but as you want just your matching sub-document and you don't know where is your target sub-document (for example the query should be on `Text1` or `Text2` , ...) there is a good data structure for this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("548dd9261a01c68fab8d67d7"),
    "pair" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "2",
            "key" : "Text1"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : [ 
                "2", 
                "3"
            ],
            "key" : "Text2"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "1",
            "key" : "Text3"
        }
    ]
}
```

and your query is:

```
db.myCollection.findOne({'pair.id' : "2"} , {'pair.$':1, _id : -1}).pair // there is better ways (such as aggregation instead of above query)
```

as result you will have:

```
{
    "0" : {
        "id" : "2",
        "key" : "Text1"
    }
}
```

**Update 1 (newbie way)**

If you want all the document not just one use this

```
var result = [];
db.myCollection.find({'pair.id' : "2"} , {'pair.$':1, _id : -1}).forEach(function(item)
{
    result.push(item.pair);
});

// the output will be in result
```

**Update 2**

Use this query to get all  sub-documents

```
db.myCollection.aggregate
(
   { $unwind: '$pair' },
   { $match : {'pair.id' : "2"} }
).result
```

it produce output as

```
{
    "0" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("548deb511a01c68fab8d67db"),
        "pair" : {
            "id" : "2",
            "key" : "Text1"
        }
    },
    "1" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("548deb511a01c68fab8d67db"),
        "pair" : {
            "id" : [ 
                "2", 
                "3"
            ],
            "key" : "Text2"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help, but isnt there a way (a structure) in which i could extract the data using db.myCollection.find({"Text1.id" : "2"}).
I saw it also on the internet as answers

Comment: as @styvane soukossi answered, yes you can, but you have to know your target field which in this case is "Text1.id"

Comment: I know, if it was working i would have changed my structure so i will fit,But it didnt work.

Comment: What didn't work? my solution or @styvane soukossi solution? I tested mine and his(or her ;)) and both working. ( in my solution use db.myCollection.find(..) anstead of db.b.find(..)

Comment: What is the error?. for me @styvane query produce this doc (query works fine) {
    "_id" : ObjectId("548de19b1a01c68fab8d67d8"),
    "Text1" : {
        "id" : "2"
    }
}

Comment: I tried your way, and it worked. but it only returned the first object in the array that matched the query (i tried find and not only findone), i tried changing some of the parameters in the second {}. Can you explain a little more about this?

Comment: @asdsd, I added 2 ways to get the result. The **Update2** offers you a better way

Comment: Thank you! It works, By the way, do you know how can i convert this query to query i can use in node.js?

Comment: My major specialty is c# and I have no idea about node.js ;(

Answer (score 2):

Since your are query specify a field in a subdocument this is what will work. see [**`.find()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db-collection-find) documentation.

```
db.myCollection.find({"Text1.id" : "2"}, {"Text1.id": true})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("548dd798e2fa652e675af11d"), "Text1" : { "id" : "2" } }
```

---

If the query is on "Text1" or "Text2" the best thing to do here as mention in the accepted answer is changing you document structure. This can be easily done using the ["Bulk"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) API.

```
var bulk = db.mycollection.initializeOrderedBulkOp(),
    count = 0;

db.mycollection.find().forEach(function(doc) { 
    var pair = []; 
    for(var key in doc) {     
        if(key !== "_id") { 
            var id = doc[key]["id"].split(/[, ]/); 
            pair.push({"key": key, "id": id}); 
        }
    } 
    bulk.find({"_id": doc._id}).replaceOne({ "pair": pair });  
    count++; if (count % 300 == 0){ 
        // Execute per 300 operations and re-Init
        bulk.execute();     
        bulk = db.mycollection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
    } 
})

// Clean up queues
if (count % 300 != 0 )
    bulk.execute();
```

Your document now look like this:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("55edddc6602d0b4fd53a48d8"),
        "pair" : [
                {
                        "key" : "Text1",
                        "id" : [
                                "2"
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "key" : "Text2",
                        "id" : [
                                "2",
                                "3"
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "key" : "Text3",
                        "id" : [
                                "1"
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
```

---

Running the following query:

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([
    { "$project": { 
        "pair": {
            "$setDifference": [
                { "$map": {
                    "input": "$pair", 
                    "as": "pr", 
                    "in": { 
                        "$cond": [
                            { "$setIsSubset": [ ["2"], "$$pr.id" ]}, 
                            "$$pr", 
                            false
                        ]
                    }
                }}, 
                [false]
            ]
        }
    }}
])
```

returns:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("55edddc6602d0b4fd53a48d8"),
        "pair" : [
                {
                        "key" : "Text1",
                        "id" : [
                                "2"
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "key" : "Text2",
                        "id" : [
                                "2",
                                "3"
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
```